# configuring juniper ssg 20 VIP

Tags: firewall, juniper

We have juniper ssg 20 and wanto access our camera system from outside network.
I have defined a new port(82) on Policy/Services/Custom screen.
And unTrust interface I have added new VIP service for 82 port from our net IP to internal IP.
But still cano not access to camera system.
Are there any settings that we have to configure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed. I have updated the policy allowing 82 port on Policy/Policies screen.